# How to implement database table for "test attempts"

Tags: python, django

i have the following database setup with the models `Test`, `Question`, `Answer` and now `Attempt`.

[image: Database Setup]

I have some issues with how to implement the `Attempt` model. Its for keeping track of test attempt results, like this:
[image: Attempts table]

How do i setup `Attempt` so i can register it with `admin.site.register(Attempt)` and see how many correct or wrong answers i got. The number of correct/wrong answers should be a link which redirects me to a page which shows what answers have been answered correct/wrong. All i got is this:

```
class Attempt(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    correct = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    wrong = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # list of answer ids that have been answered correct
    list = () # ?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A table that joins the question and attempt tables would work from what I can see.

```
class QuestionAttempt(models.Model):
    attempt = models.ForeignKey(Attempt)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer)
```

So for a given Attempt instance you can get all the QuestionAttempt records, and determine whether they were correct or incorrect.